# I would like to advertise one of my app by inserting an interstitial in another my app using admob

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I would like to advertise one of my app by inserting its advertisement in an interstitial of another of my apps through admob.
How can I set the auto-promotional campaign in admob?
I tried to start a self-promotional campaign in admob.
currently admob tells me that the campaign is active but starting the old app, in the interstitial of the old app, continue to appear ads offered by google and does not appear the ad illustrated by me uploaded as interstitial.

I went to create a new campaign in admob and on the type of campaign to choose I flagged a self-promotional ad (Promote your apps and websites).
Subsequently in type of objective I have chosen announcements with mediation (recommended for the backfill).
the other choices for the type of target were:
- Number of impressions
- Number of clicks
- Percentage of impressions;

In the next step admob asked me to select an ad unit and I chose my app as an ad unit to use.
I removed the banners and left only interstitial.
In create new ad I selected "an app on google play" and in select the Android app to advertise I selected my new app from the play store.
I have selected illustrated ad
I have inserted the link of URL of destination of the page of the app to advertise, I have loaded the requested image in type of file PNG size 480x320 and size 63 KB requested by admob
Now admob also showed me the preview, which it didn't do before when I had uploaded an image of the wrong size.
Admob tells me that the campaign is activated but in practice does not appear the ad in the old app where it should appear, but instead continue to appear ads google.
Thank you for your availability